# Run multiple processes at once in Python and concat results

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, parallel-processing

Let's say I have a directory which has 20 files within it:

```
path1 = "/path/to/data"
dir1 = os.listdir(path1)
```

These 20 files are basically 20 tiles of a large grid. I load each individually, run a process, then concatenate them after the process is complete. The general process looks like:

```
finaldata = []
alldata = []
loopdata = []
for i in dir1:
    loopdata = np.load(i)
    alldata = run_process(loopdata)
    if len(finaldata) == 0:
        finaldata = alldata
    else:
        finaldata = np.concatenate((finaldata,alldata))
```

Which will give me what I want, but it is rather slow. However, there are multiprocessing and threading options available in python to potentially split the processing into 20 different processes, and then properly concatenate the results in the end. How would something like this work in Python 3.6+?

Comment: This is all a bit vague. You have 20 files... are they images? PNGs? JPEGs? What size are they in pixels by pixels? Does your machine have enough RAM and CPU cores to process them in parallel? Does the processing on one tile affect neighbouring tiles... e.g. an area process that blurs with a large radius across tile boundaries? Is the processing very intensive relative to the combining afterwards? How long does it currently take?